# Mono<Mono<>> как исправить?

Tags: java

```
public Mono<Page<Dto>> getAll(Pageable pageable, Filter filter) {

    Mono<Mono<Page<Dto>>> rrr = freightBooleanBuilder.byBaseFreightCriteria(filter)
                         .map(e->
                            mapToDtoPage(this.repository.findAll(e, pageable.getSort()), pageable,
                     repository, mapper));
 
return rrr;
```

всё шло прекрасно но mapToDtoPage(this.repository.findAll(e, pageable.getSort()), pageable,
repository, mapper) возвращает

```
Mono<Page<Dto>>
```

по этому получается

```
Mono<Mono<Page<Dto>>>
```

как можно поправить чтобы на выходе получалось

```
Mono<Page<Dto>>
```

Comment: Предполагаю, что если вы замените ваш последний `.map()` на `.flatMap()`, то получите желаемый результат.
Если это не поможет, то после существующего map можно добавить еще одно преобразование:
`.flatMap(value -> value)`

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант #1**

В конце вашего pipe добавить еще одно преобразование:

```
.flatMap(value -> value)
```

*Примечание: данное решение не самое эффективное вследствие добавления еще одного преобраования, которое, в теории, можно избежать.*

**Вариант #2**

На одном из предыдущих шагов выполнить иное преобразование.
Чтобы наверняка подсказать где и как его выполинть нужно видеть остальные ваши методы, которые здесь вызываются.

Предположительно, это может быть сделано посредством замены вашего последнего `.map()` на `.flatMap()`.